# TailwindCSS Resizable Columns

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to build a resizable column table, with TailwindCSS, following this example on [Tanstack](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tanstack/table/tree/main/examples/react/full-width-resizable-table?file=/src/main.tsx).

When I inspect the generated HTML code, the Width class is added to the `td` as `w-[30px]`, which is my expected result, but TailwindCSS is simply ignoring it, even when I use the `table-fixed` and the `resize` class.

I wonder if then changing the width once the table is rendered is supported or is there a class that I am missing.

According to the [Tailwind Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/table-layout#fixed):

> You can manually set the widths for some columns and the rest of the available width will be divided evenly amongst the columns without explicit width.

I tried already allowing only 3 out of the 5 columns in my table to be resizable, the result is the same.

This is a simplified definition of my table:

```js
<table className="w-full text-center mb-12 table-fixed">
   <thead className="border-0 top-0 sticky bg-white">
       <tr>
           <th className={`text-gray-700 font-bold w-[${column.getSize()}px]`}
                   {header.getContext()}
           </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td className={`text-gray-300 w-[${column.getSize()}px] `}
               {cell.getContext()}
           </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using dynamic class names: `w-[${column.getSize()}px]`

That can't be done in Tailwind, see https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Instead you could try setting the width as a style rather than class.